# Language change onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create 1 page within my website that is French (the rest is English), so I was looking into jQuery to do this. Is this the best way to do this?

I want this to fire on pageload that will work on multiple browsers, at the moment I am using HTML replace.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("body").children().each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Download/g, "FranceDownload"));
  });
  
  $("body").children().each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Document/g, "FranceDocument"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Onload this document will Translate to French.<br><br>
<div>Download - Document</div>
```

I have created the following codepen to show this:  https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/dybOdgw

This changes the documents language as wanted, as the user will manually code in the words they want changed.

Is there a better way to do this? Do I need to fire the "$("body").children().each(function ()" each time?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, using this plugin http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/ will be more readily scalable and maintainable

Comment: To answer your last question: no, you could do it one pass - call the **$.each()** once, and replace everything with your regular expressions. But there are better ways altogether to do this - in the answers below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use plugins, and only the textual content needs to be translated, then I think you'd better just create a small dictionary, and use that for your page. (OK, it tolerates HTML too.)

I mimicked the **onload** with a toggle button, but the function itself can be used anywhere in your code (where it "sees" the **dict** object and the **lang** variable).

The only markup you need is the **data-translate** attribute on the element containing the text and an item in the **dict** object.

```js
const dict = {
  "0": {
    en: "Download - Document",
    fr: "Télécharger - Document"
  },
  "1": {
    en: "It's not a document",
    fr: "Ce n'est pas un document"
  },
  "2": {
    en: "Translate this, while you<br />are fast asleep.",
    fr: "Traduisez ceci pendant que<br />vous êtes endormi."
  }
}

let lang = 'en'

const btnLang = document.getElementById('toggleLang')

// click event: toggle language
btnLang.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  lang = lang === 'en' ? 'fr' : 'en'
  toggleLang(lang)
})

// toggle language (using lang variable and dict object)
function toggleLang(lang) {
  const toTranslate = document.querySelectorAll("[data-translate]")
  toTranslate.forEach(e => {
    e.innerHTML = dict[e.getAttribute('data-translate')][lang]
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Onload this document will Translate to French.<br><br>
<button id="toggleLang">Toggle language</button>
<div data-translate="0">Download - Document</div><br><br>
<div data-translate="1">It's not a document</div><br><br>
<div data-translate="2">Translate this, while you<br />are fast asleep.</div>
```

While this is an easy solution (and really smally in terms of bytes), it's not foolproof: you have to take care of the **dict** object (so it has all elements that are referenced in the HTML) and also that all items have all the language variations you want.

But if you want to have a more thorough solution I would say look at **i18n** for jQuery (https://blog.lokalise.co/localizing-apps-jquery/,  or https://dzone.com/articles/localize-your-app-with-jqueryi18n). **i18n** is quite a standard of internationalization (or localization), that you may meet in a lot of "places": Wordpress (WPML), JS frameworks (like VueJS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-i18n). So, if you use it in this case, you may learn something that can come in handy later on. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!! Very helpful :)

Comment: I'm happy that I could help you out! :)